# Pointers to base classes and how to determine actual type of the instance

Tags: c++, oop

I have a problem and I'm not sure how to approach it in C++;

I have three objects that can each perform a number of different actions. These objects support an add-on object that adds to the actions they can perform. Depending to the object it is added to, the add on will enable different actions.

How would I model this in C++?

I would like to have classes A, B, C, AddOn1, AddOn2.

The problem is:

How does AddOn1/2 know at runtime what actions it contains ( in other words how does it know what (type of) object it is attached to )?

How does class A, B, C know what type of add-on it has?

I would like to do something like

class A {
...
AddOn* addOn;
};

And use that pointer to work with the add-on. But I need to cast it into its specific class to be able to use its functions.

I can see how I can have boolean fields like hasAddOn1 and hasAddOn2 and cast based on these settings. Then in the AddOn base class I could have a pointer to its parent and interrogate the parent to find out the type of the AddOn.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

> I have three objects that can each perform a number of different actions. These objects support an add-on object that adds to the actions they can perform. Depending to the object it is added to, the add on will enable different actions.

Why not use inheritance and templates?

```
struct A {
  virtual void action_foo(); // virtual not really needed in this example
};

struct B {
  virtual void action_bar();
};

template<class base_t>
struct AddOn1 : base_t {
  virtual void action_baz();
};

void func(A& a) {
  a->action_foo();
}

// example of use

A x;
B y;
AddOn1<A> z; // add on to A
x.action_foo();
y.action_bar();
z.action_baz();
func(x);
func(z);
```